# Delphi IDE hangs after performing Install of Package

Tags: delphi, installation, package

I am trying to install a commercial Package by loading the DPROJ file, Compiling it (succeeds) and then Installing.  When I try to Install, the compile progress box appears for an instant, and then the IDE becomes unresponsive.  It is not using significant CPU resources, so it is not in a tight loop.

How do I go about attempting to diagnose what the problem is?

Comment: You can start by adding information about the nature of your project, your Delphi version, and maybe even some source code.

Comment: Looks like there's a problem with the code. Where to start is to strip out code from the package to narrow down the culprit. Or to debug package load.

Comment: If the package is commercial it sure got tech support that will help you.

Comment: Come on, guys, go easy on him.  He's a new user, and he's given plenty of useful information here.  No need to bury someone's first question in downvotes just because it's not described in enough detail for you to reproduce locally.

Comment: @MasonWheeler: the world needs more people like you.

Answer (score 10):

This really isn't much to go on--it would really help if we knew the name of the package and which version of Delphi you were using--but I'll take a crack at it.  At least you've done a good job of describing the problem you're observing. A lot of new users don't even do that much.

You said you were able to compile.  I hope that means this came with source.  If not--if you got a commercial, DCU-only library--you've been ripped off.  Call up the people who created it and take them to task over it.

But let's assume you have source code.  If so, this problem is actually fairly easy to track down.  Here's what you do:

- Open *two* copies of Delphi, load the package into both of them, and compile.  Make sure debug info is turned on.
- In one copy, try to install the package.  Wait for it to hang.
- Switch to the other copy of Delphi.
- In the menu, go to `Run->Attach to Process...`
- Attach to the other copy of BDS.exe.  (If you can't tell which is which, it's pretty easy: you can't attach to your own process, so it's the one that it'll let you connect to.) This will attach the debugger to the other copy of Delphi.

  - If it doesn't automatically break to the debugger, hit Pause.
- Switch to the main thread and check out the call stack.  If you don't find anything useful, check in other threads.
- If it's not burning lots of CPU, it's probably hung waiting on a lock somewhere.  Look for a call to `WaitFor<something>Object(s)` in the main thread.

From there, have fun debugging!  That's all the help I can give you based on the information available, but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Upvoting not only because of genuinely helpful suggestions, but also because you are attempting to restore the conversation to the level we want here at SO. Thank you.

Comment: I have a similar problem in a library of my own. Except in my case, the IDE completely crashes, followed by crashing on startup (until I delete my BPL). Just poof, splash screen disappears, no error or anything. So your suggested debug method won't work. Anyway, I have property editors, and I suspect a recent change to one may be the culprit. But have been digging for the past hour... :-/